# Using a password text box in a DataForm with Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, dataform

Is there an idiomatic way to indicate that a field in this model should be a password text box:

```
public class User
{
   [Required]
   public string Username { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

If there isn't an idiomatic way to auto-generate a password text box, is there a better way than hooking into one of the auto generation events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not.  If you take a look at the LoginForm class in a project created using the Silverlight Business Application project template, you'll find that it makes use of a custom control (CustomDataForm, also in the project) to help achieve this same functionality.  So you can grab this and use it in your project in place of the standard DataForm control if you want.  Otherwise, simply provide your own EditTemplate for the DataForm instead (which is usually my preferred means when using the DataForm control instead of having it automatically generate the controls).  It's more work to do so, but it's also much more flexible way to lay out data forms.

Hope this helps...

Chris

Comment: Since it's open source, is contributing a set of display attributes is a good idea? It seems that even if it does, it only fits into the view model so you can't connect a model directly. Good idea? Bad idea? what do you think?

Comment: Microsoft doesn't accept any contributions to the Silverlight Toolkit unfortunately. So I typically recommend against making any changes to the source in the Silverlight Toolkit as it will create problems for you when new versions of the Toolkit are released.  Maybe leave a request on the CodePlex site or Silverlight's user voice site for it as a new feature?

Comment: Thanks, Why for the love of god is it open sourced than?

Comment: Not sure, apart from the fact that it gives you the ability to modify the source if required (which I recommend against), or use parts of the code in your own projects (such as if you were creating your own custom controls).  It's good as learning material as well.  Anyhow, I'm glad it's available even if we can't contribute back to it :).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help: [Silverlight DataForm DataField vs PasswordBox](http://ryoushin.com/cmerighi/en-us/2011-10-01_95/Silverlight_DataForm_DataField_vs_PasswordBox). It's a workaround that actually hooks into the `AutoGeneratingField` event.